# how could a computer in the first dimension perform multiplication?

Tags: physics, computers, dimensions

If it is possible for a computer in the first dimension to perform a second dimensional operation in the same way a computer in the second dimension can perform a third dimensional operation, then maybe a third dimensional computer could perform a fourth dimensional operation.

We already have 2d computers, so what i am wondering is how would a 1d computer work out multiplication. I've theorized that the physics of this 1d world that it is built in would have 8 characteristics to work with:

1. length is mass
2. there can be charged particles(lines) that attract/repel each other
3. there can be gravity of attraction or repulsion between masses(your choice)
4. there can be lines splitting or combining, but the rules for both must be given.
5. there may be limits set on the world (example: a speed limit like the speed of 
   light. or an edge where things )
6. there can be "optimal lengths" where a line is more/less stable(optional)
7. we are only allowed to put "input lines" (which will be multiplied) into either 1 area or two
8. the outputs may be anywhere, but you must be able to read them all.

what determines a successful "computer" would be if it is capable of multiplying any single digit number from 0-9 with another from 0-9.

edit: if it makes it easier to think of, the whole system can be reset each time you want to use it with new inputs(i realize it would be nearly impossible to reset itself).

Comment: I think we already have this, right? All of the data on a spinning disk hard drive is stored basically in a string of numbers, which is etched into a spiral shape. So in effect, all of our math operations are already 1D. If I’m understanding the requirement correctly.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to understand what kind of questions we answer here, and then please try to clarify your question. I have problems understanding what you are asking.

Comment: @Vladimir you could theoretically unfold a disk that way and you would have the memory, but how would it perform any operations?

Comment: @theRiley I was thinking was maybe the two inputs would be the length of the input and the speed it is coming in would be multiplied, or two inputs of known length were put in either side or in the same side. really the way you put both input numbers in doesn't matter, so long as you always get the correct answer

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your meaning when you say "second-dimensional-", "third-dimensional-", "fourth-dimensional operation". Performing math in multiple dimensions is really just performing math in the one dimension, multiple times in series.

Comment: Agreed with @Cadence comment. Algebra can be generalized to be n-dimensional, so no problems there.

Comment: An important piece of this puzzle would be the concept of "reification," which is taking something abstract and creating a concrete represntation fo it.  For example, our computers *cannot* do true 3-dimensional operations, such as rotations in 3-space.  What they *can* do is calculate (approximate) matrices which represent that concept of rotation in a more concrete way.

Comment: And... snap.  If you can get this question past StephenG and LDutch so it can be opened, there is a de-facto answer to this: [Rule 110](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_110).  Rule 110 is a 1-d cellular automata that has 1 spatial dimension (plus 1 time dimension for time-evolution, of course).  It is proven to be Turing complete, thus it is as powerful as any computer we have, while being described not only in 1 dimension *but also* it also only requires interactions between negihbors, no action at a distance.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen, because I think that it is so clear what they are asking for that there's 2 decades of mathematical papers published on the answer: Rule 110.

Comment: @CortAmmon, While what you're saying has a geek factor that is, frankly, off the charts, I simply can't tell if by saying "one-dimensional" the OP means the programmatic context of Rule 110, or spacially 1-D (e.g., a line if considered from the point of view of a cube as 3-D, or a single point if we're counting vertices).  The reason I point this out is because the question, as written, doesn't suggest the sophistication to understand Rule 110, and therefore suggests that "one-dimensional" is referring to spatial dimensions.  It'd be nice if I was wrong, of course.

Comment: @BluePiston - Responding to your reply to my comment: While registers on a processor are layed out in a grid, I can’t think of any reason (besides efficiency) why they can’t be put into a line. But as someone mentioned in an another comment, if you consider time as a dimension, then this would technically be 2D; and in this case, I cant think of any “trully” 1D computer. But I’m not sure if you’d want to make such a restriction, since a universe with no time might not be very interesting.

Comment: I’d forgotten Rule 110. Much more intuitive than my Turing machine example but potentially trickier to implement in a 1d space..

Comment: FYI, the way data is stored has no bearing on the ability to compute anything in higher dimensions. In many fields of human science we already work with problems with well over thousands of dimensions.

Answer (score 8):

You may wish to look into [Turing Machines](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine), a mathematical model that is a one dimensional string of on/off states and a ‘moving head’ that can move up and down the line and alter the state of the bits. Any computer algorithm is theoretically possible on a correctly made Turing machine. A full 6 step algorithm for simple multiplication can be found [here](https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/turing-machine-for-multiplication/amp/) (I’ll transcribe the steps to this answer when I can).

If your universe is capable of sustaining anything that would care about this computation then it must also be capable of sustaining such a construct. Voila: 1D computers.

Comment: A virtual implementation of a Turing machine can be found in the programming language Brainfuck (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck), the recipe for multiplying two numbers is on the wikipedia page. Several real world interpreters for the language exist and there are tags on other stackexchanges (codegolf, softwareengineering, codereview and stackexchange itself).

Comment: Not really 1D, even a Turing computer needs two dimensions, one spatial and on temporal.

Comment: @Kain: if you discount time as a concept the the OP’s characteristics 2,3,4 and 5, along with the concept of ‘output’ are all impossibilities. Add to that the fact that we’re currently unsure how many dimensions we live in and I think it’s pretty clear the OP was referring to spatial dimensions.